# Python: What does _("str") do?

Tags: python, syntax

I see this in the Django source code:

```
description = _("Comma-separated integers")
description = _("Date (without time)")
```

What does it do? I try it in Python 3.1.3 and it fails:

```
>>> foo = _("bar")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    foo = _("bar")
NameError: name '_' is not defined
```

No luck in 2.4.4 either:

```
>>> foo = _("bar")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in -toplevel-
    foo = _("bar")
NameError: name '_' is not defined
```

What's going on here?

Comment: This is usually used to mark strings as translatable for GNU gettext.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The name `_` is an ordinary name like any other. The syntax `_(x)` is calling the function called `_` with the argument `x`. In this case it is used as an alias for `ugettext`, which is defined by Django. This function is used for translation of strings. From the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/internationalization/):

> #### Specifying translation strings: In Python code
>
> **Standard translation**
>
> Specify a translation string by using the function ugettext(). It’s convention to import this as a shorter alias, _, to save typing.

To use `_` in your own code you can use an import like this:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
```

Comment: Like here: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/validators.py#L5

Answer (score 1):

The symbol `_` is just a variable name in python, and in this case it looks like it refers to a function or other "callable" which takes a string as an argument. For example

```
 def myfun(strng):
     return "input = " +  strng

 _ = myfun

 description = _("Comma-separated integers")
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that you cannot choose any alias to want, if you want ``makemessages```to detect the strings.